# Updating weight in previous layers in Backpropagation

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I am trying to create a simple neural network and stuck at updating the weights at first layer in two layers. I imagine the first update I am doing to w2 are correct as what I learned from back propagation algorithm. I am not including bias for now. But how do we update the first layer weights is where I am stuck at.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0/(1+ np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return x * (1.0 - x)

def cost_function(output, y):
    return (output - y) ** 2

x = 2
y = 4

w1 = np.random.rand()
w2 = np.random.rand()

h = sigmoid(w1 * x)
o = sigmoid(h * w2)

cost_function_output = cost_function(o, y)

prev_w2 = w2

w2 -= 0.5 * 2 * cost_function_output * h * sigmoid_derivative(o) # 0.5 being learning rate

w1 -= 0 # What do you update this to?

print(cost_function_output)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not able to comment on your question, so writing here.
Firstly, your sigmoid_derivative function is wrong.
The derivative of `sigmoid(x*y) w.r.t x is = sigmoid(x*y)*(1-sigmoid(x*y))*y`.

Edit: (deleted unnecessary text)

We need dW1 and dW2 (These are `dJ/dW1` and `dJ/dW` (partial derivatives) respectively.

`J = (o - y)^2` therefore `dJ/do = 2*(o - y)`

Now, dW2

```
dJ/dW2 = dJ/do * do/dW2 (chain rule)
dJ/dW2 = (2*(o - y)) * (o*(1 - o)*h)
dW2 (equals above equation)
W2 -= learning_rate*dW2
```

Now, for dW1

```
dJ/dh = dJ/do * do/dh = (2*(o - y)) * (o*(1 - o)*W2  
dJ/dW1 = dJ/dh * dh/dW1 = ((2*(o - y)) * (o*(1 - o)*W2)) * (h*(1- h)*x)  
dW1 (equals above equation)
W1 -= learning_rate*dW2
```

PS: Try to make a computational graphs, finding derivatives become a lot more easier. (If you don't know this, read it online)

Comment: I just updated the code, I learnt about the chain rule and was able to figure out the last weight as you can see in the code. I am stuck as how the w1 gets updated after w2 is updated.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to understand the following values.